# Why won't this jQuery one-liner do what it is supposed to?

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm working on some form UI coding and wrote this jQuery one-liner:

> $('input[type=text]').val($(this).attr('default-value'));

Intention is to give every input text field its default value which is supplied within an attribute.

Any suggestions?
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
   $(this).val($(this).attr('default-value'));
});
```

The problem with yours is that `$(this)` wasn't defined in the context you were using it in.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).attr('default-value'));
});
```

`this` inside your `val()` call isn't referencing the element, but it's simply the context of the function where you're running this one-liner.

Also, when defining custom attributes, you might consider investing in HTML5 earlier on and use the "data-*" convention: In HTML5 it is legal to define custom attributes as long as they are prefixed with "data-". So, I would use something like "data-default" instead of "default-value".

Comment: As with the HMTL5 convention: This isn't mine to choose. Thanks anyways for bringing this up.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't working because the context of `this` isn't what you'd expect. Try this:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val($this.attr('default-value'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

`$('input[type=text]').val(function(i,e) { return  $(e).attr('default-value'); } );`

Answer (score -1):

Because you aren't referencing the element correctly...

You are immediately assigning the val of the input to the current scope of `$(this)` instead of the element you are getting.

```
$(":text").each(function() { $(this).val($(this).attr('default-value')); });
```